# Accessing a widget within a QStackWidget

Tags: c++, qt, vector, qstackedwidget

I'm creating dynamic widgets using the following code:

```
//class constructor
counter = 0; //int

//class method
vec_txt.push_back(new QTextBrowser()); //vector
ui->stackedWidget->addWidget(vec_txt[counter]);
counter++;
```

Now, I want to save the text in a file, but I don't know how to access the `QTextBrowser` object that is in the `QStackWidget` stackedWidget.

Is it even possible?

Comment: what exactly is a `vec_txt`? Why you have problem with saving the file? What exactly you want to achieve?

Comment: Why do you have the vector vec_txt if not for accessing the QTextBrowser?

Comment: @Zlatomir how do i access it through vector? `vec_txt[index]->toPlainText();` doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible, just retrieve the widget at the desired *index* with [this method](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstackedwidget.html#widget) :

```
QTextBrowser* textBrowser = qobject_cast<QTextBrowser*>(stackedWidget->widget(index));
```

Comment: Some fix: QTextBrowser* textBrowser = qobject_cast<QTextBrowser*>(stackedWidget->widget(index));